# Spring Boot + Elastic Search+Maven

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying with simple spring boot application to connect elastic search. I facing problem on starting an application on ApplicationContext.

It Shows like this

> Error
>    Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'studentController' method 
>   public java.util.Optional com.springboot.main.StudentController.getStudent(long)
>   to {[/student],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'studentController' bean method
>   public com.springboot.main.Student com.springboot.main.StudentController.show(long,java.lang.String,int) mapped.
>   2018-05-09 16:14:50.512  INFO 24984 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2018-05-09 16:14:50.552  INFO 24984 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
>   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2018-05-09 16:14:50.559 ERROR 24984 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Here

> My Pom.xml file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot_elastic</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springboot_elastic</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
<optional>true</optional>
```

```
</dependencies>
```

> Please help me to solve this  problem

Comment: read the error message. there are obviously two beans of type `StudentController` that both want to occupy the `/student` endpoint. Solution: check why it's instantiated twice.

Comment: Thank you for helping , the error rectified